# ¿ Como crear un widget desde un activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-widget

Ya tengo echo el widget, lo agrege en el manifest, la interfza y la funcionialidad del mismo

Lo que quiero es que a traves de un boton en un activty, se ponga el widget , esto para que el usuario pueda poner y/o quitar el widget desde un activity

Se puede hacer esto???

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesita extender la clase [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) en su aplicación. Vea un tutorial [aquí](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part1) y asegúrese de seguir las [pautas de diseño](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html).

**Un pequeño ejemplo:

El widget tiene una imagen y cuando se toca la imagen, debe iniciarse la aplicación. Buscando un fragmento.

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    //Crear una intención para iniciar la actividad
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.home_widget);
    //Cuando hacemos clic en el widget, queremos abrir nuestra actividad principal.
    Intent launchActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchActivity, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);;

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

Diseño de widgets:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widgetLauncher"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/wgt_logo" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Aquí tiene un [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-an-android-widget/) de interés.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está lo que estás buscando.

```
public void confirmConfiguration(View v) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , me funciono correctamente